# Excel- VBA: Given a start and end date, create an array of the dates between the two

Tags: vba, excel

I need an **Excel-VBA** Solution for below mentioned Issue. The solution I am working with is perfect but very slow and nearly kills my PC for IDs more than 500. (and I have 10000+ IDs to process.)

I have Start Date and end date for some IDs,

**Data Set 1**

```
ID          Trans_Date     Action
1234567890  01-Jan-2012    Active
1234567890  05-Jan-2012    Dc
1234567890  06-Jan-2012    Active
1234567890  12-Jan-2012     Dc
1234567890  15-Jan-2012    Active
```

I need to expand the set as below,

**Required data set,**

```
ID          Trans_Date  Action
1234567890  01-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  02-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  03-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  04-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  05-Jan-12   DC
1234567890  06-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  07-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  08-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  09-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  10-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  11-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  12-Jan-12   DC
1234567890  13-Jan-12   DC
1234567890  14-Jan-12   DC
1234567890  15-Jan-12   Active
```

Currently I’m using the formula given below.

(Thanks to [**Tom Sharpe**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894917/tom-sharpe))

```
1) Copy the first ID number into D2

(2) Put this formula in D3

=IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D2,D2)<(MAX(IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20))-MIN(IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20))+1),
   D2,
   INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:D2, $A$2:$A$20), 0)))
(3) Put this formula in E2:-

=MIN(IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20))+COUNTIF(D$1:D1,D2)
(4) Put this formula in F2:-

=INDEX(C$2:C$20,MATCH(E2,IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20),1))
All these are array formulae and must be entered with CtrlShiftEnter
```

[image]

But even he is suggesting to use VBA. How to do it in VBA ?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the criteria to know that you have reached the last date you want to manage ? Is it the last one in the data set for each ID ? is it todays' date ?

Comment: Today's Date, which will carry the last action to the point (today). Thanks

Comment: Please add more explanation to your question - describe what you want the code to do.

Comment: Have you tried to program something already or do you expect someone to just write the code for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. You will need to modify the sheet references and columns depending on where the data is. The expanded data will now list in the second sheet.

```
Sub ExpandData()

Dim SourceRow, TargetRow As Long
Dim LastDate, NextDate As Date
Dim DateDiff, FillDate As Integer
SourceRow = 2
TargetRow = 2

'Loop through source rows
Do While Sheets(1).Range("A" & CStr(SourceRow)).Value <> ""
    LastDate = Sheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(SourceRow)).Value
    ' Check for the last row of data and use todays date if last row
    If Sheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(SourceRow + 1)).Value <> "" Then
        NextDate = Sheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(SourceRow + 1)).Value
    Else
        NextDate = Date
    End If
    DateDiff = NextDate - LastDate
    ' create a row in the target sheet for each date in between those in the source sheet
    For FillDate = 0 To DateDiff - 1
        Sheets(2).Range("A" & CStr(TargetRow)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A" & CStr(SourceRow)).Value
        Sheets(2).Range("B" & CStr(TargetRow)).Value = LastDate + FillDate
        Sheets(2).Range("C" & CStr(TargetRow)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("C" & CStr(SourceRow)).Value
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
    Next FillDate

    SourceRow = SourceRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome. The source list needs to be sorted in ascending date order for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim cl As Range, i&, z&, x&, key As Variant
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    z = 1
    For Each cl In Range("A2:A" & i)
    x = 1
    If cl = cl.Offset(1, 0) And _
        Trim(cl.Offset(, 2)) <> Trim(cl.Offset(1, 2)) Then
            Dic.Add z, cl & "|" & cl.Offset(, 1) & "|" & cl.Offset(, 2)
            While cl.Offset(, 1) + x < cl.Offset(1, 1)
                z = z + 1
                Dic.Add z, cl & "|" & cl.Offset(, 1) + x & "|" & cl.Offset(, 2)
                x = x + 1
            Wend
    Else
        Dic.Add z, cl & "|" & cl.Offset(, 1) & "|" & cl.Offset(, 2)
    End If
    z = z + 1
    Next cl
    Workbooks.Add
    x = 2: [A1] = "ID": [B1] = "Trans_Date": [C1] = "Action"
    For Each key In Dic
        Range(Cells(x, "A"), Cells(x, "C")) = Split(Dic(key), "|")
        x = x + 1
    Next key
    Columns("A:C").AutoFit
End Sub
```

**source**

[image]

**output result**

[image]